# Getting decimal values in MySQL issue

Tags: mysql

I have a column with a lot of rows. My rows are look like:

```
1.0000
2.0000
1.7500
3.2500
3.0000
1.0000
2.0000
47.000
1.2500
0.7500
......
```

I would like to get all of the data where the decimal parts are greater then zero in a query.  How can I do that ? 
I would do smth like

`select * from table where (column = 1.7500) OR (column = 0.75000)  ....` but they are too many.  Thank you

Comment: What is the **data type** of your column?

Comment: `DECIMAL(12,4)` is the data type , thnx

Comment: What do you mean by "decimal parts are greater then zero"? Do you mean decimal part different than 0, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just compare the value to the value without the decimal part.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE your_column != FLOOR(your_column)
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/19d309/1/0)

Comment: Lovely, Thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Or try the MOD-operator:

```
select id from t
where MOD(id, 1) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to the one given by @fancyPants would be using the modulo operation in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MOD(column, 1) != 0
```

Documentation for `MOD` operation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html